# Differential equation with some condition

Tags: differential-equations, constraint

I'm trying to solve a harmonic oscillator equation with a time-dependent (real) frequency,

$v_k''(\tau) + \omega_k^2(\tau) v_k(\tau)=0$,

where

$\omega_k^2(\tau) = k^2 - \frac{2}{\tau^2}$.

This equation has a two-dimensional space of solutions $\{v_k, v_k^*\}$.
In order to specify the mode function $v_k$ I have to impose the following conditions,

$v'_k v_k^* -v_k v{'}_k^* =-i,$

$\lim_{\tau \rightarrow- \infty} v_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}Exp[- i k \tau]$.

Naively, I have tried to implement those conditions into

```
ParametricNDSolveValue function:
xlns = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Xl''[\[Tau]] + (k^2 - 
          2/\[Tau]^2) Xl[\[Tau]]) == 0, 
    Xl[\[Tau]] Conjugate[Xl'[\[Tau]]] - 
      Conjugate[Xl[\[Tau]]] Xl'[\[Tau]] == -I, 
    Xl[\[Tau]i] == 1/Sqrt[ 2 k ] Exp[-I k \[Tau]i] }, 
   Xl, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]e}, {k}];
xln[k_, \[Tau]_] = Evaluate[xlns[k][\[Tau]]];
xln[1, \[Tau]i],
```

but I have received this message: [image]

Do you have any idea how to impose those conditions? I've also tried to use only the second condition and its derivative, but then the solution violates the first condition, which should be valid at any time.

This is my code:

```
mpl := 2.4 10^18  
\[Tau]i := - 10^12/mpl 
n := 60
\[Tau]e := \[Tau]i Exp[-n]
xlnsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Xl''[\[Tau]] + (k^2 - 
          2/\[Tau]^2) Xl[\[Tau]]) == 0, 
    Xl[\[Tau]i] == 1/Sqrt[ 2 k ] Exp[-I k \[Tau]i], 
    Xl'[\[Tau]i] == - I k Xl[\[Tau]i]}, 
   Xl, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]e}, {k}, 
   Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}];
xln[k_, \[Tau]_] = Evaluate[xlnsol[k][\[Tau]]];
xlnc[k_, \[Tau]_] = Evaluate[Conjugate[xlnsol[k][\[Tau]]]];
dxln[k_, \[Tau]_] = Evaluate[D[xlnsol[k][t], t]] /. t -> \[Tau];
dxlnc[k_, \[Tau]_] = 
  Evaluate[Conjugate[D[xlnsol[k][t], t]]] /. t -> \[Tau];
W[k_, \[Tau]_] = 
  xlnc[k, \[Tau]] dxln[k, \[Tau]] -  xln[k, \[Tau]] dxlnc[k, \[Tau]];

Plot[{Re[W[1, \[Tau]]], Im[W[1, \[Tau]]]}, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]e}]
```

[image]

I would really appreciate any feedback you can give me.

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: In your very first equation, there is v depending on tau and also v depending on k. In your further equation, there are v with the indices k. Your function omega depends somehow on tau. You do not inform us, how. You should explain and specify all those things.

Comment: You're right, I should have specified it at the very beginning. I have updated my post.

Comment: @riso The equation has an exact solution, so you can use `DSolve`. Additional restrictions mean that you want to define parameters, for example `k`.

Comment: I know that this equation can be solved analytically. Actually, I have checked that the Wronskian condition is then always satisfied. However, I am going to modify $\omega_k$ and in this case I cannot find solution using DSolve

Comment: @riso Why the solution is investigated at `t<0`? In logarithmic coordinates with `t>0`, there is a different picture.

Comment: Tau here denotes conformal time, which by definition is negative.